# SSRS report printing multiple pages

Tags: javascript, asp.net, reporting-services, printing

My asp.net application uses .rdl reports for showing reports. I have been using subreports for each report to show. The subreports are then added to the main report which is then rendered into a report viewer element on the .aspx page. When I try to print reports the current page is only printing even though the report viewer has many pages.
I have removed the page break setting in the report file but it doesn't give output as expected. When there is no page break then reports printed on the same page. If I added page break then only one page at a time is printed, but I want to print each report on separate pages at a single button click.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>        
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="reportViewer" runat="server" ProcessingMode="Remote">
    <ServerReport ReportServerUrl="https://website/ReportServer" />
</rsweb:ReportViewer>

</div>
```

c# code is given below,

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
      
        reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;

        ServerReport serverReport = reportViewer.ServerReport;

        serverReport.ReportServerUrl =
       new Uri("http://websitename:82/Reports/report");
        serverReport.ReportPath =
            "/Untitled";
    }
```

Does anyone have any solution for this? Because I am stuke with this.
Thank you

Comment: Is it a setting on your printer? Try exporting the report to Excel or PDF then try printing. If it only prints 1 page, it sounds like your print settings.

Comment: Thank you @JobesK for your response. No, it's not about the printer settings. Actually, I want to print all the pages in the report viewer without checking each page. I have removed the page navigation button on the report viewer but still, it shows and prints the first page only. Is there any other way we can print all pages on the report without exporting it to Excel or PDF?

Comment: How exactly are you executing the print action? Browser print wont work and you'll only get what you see on the page, the SSRS print function (toolbar icon/button) would be the only way but check that its not being blocked or limiting its function due to any security protocols you may have. at my work I have disabled that function (for security reasons) and the only way to print is to export then print. Best of luck, but I'm not sure what else it could be.